# Logging configuration in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, slf4j, slf4j-api

Looking the way how to configure slf4j in Spring boot app:

I add this in my application.properties:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.file=book.log
logging.level.*=DEBUG
```

I have this controller:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/book")
public class BookController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BookController.class);

@RequestMapping(value={ "/list"}, method = { RequestMethod.GET})
    public String bookList(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) throws DataAccessException, SQLException {

        logger.debug("testing...");

}
}
```

But my message is not logged in the file, but there are other messages:

```
...
2017-03-26 08:13:49.768 DEBUG 2426 --- [restartedMain] o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping      : Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.MultipartAutoConfiguration': no URL paths identified
2017-03-26 08:13:49.768 DEBUG 2426 --- [restartedMain] o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping      : Rejected bean name 'multipartConfigElement': no URL paths identified
2017-03-26 08:13:49.768 DEBUG 2426 --- [restartedMain] o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping      : Rejected bean name 'multipartResolver': no URL paths identified
2017-03-26 08:13:49.768 DEBUG 2426 --- [restartedMain] o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping      : Rejected bean name 'spring.http.multipart-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.MultipartProperties': no URL paths identified
2017-03-26 08:13:49.768 DEBUG 2426 --- [restartedMain] o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping      : Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration': no URL paths identified
2017-03-26 08:13:49.768 DEBUG 2426 --- [restartedMain] o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping      : Rejected bean name 'serverProperties': no URL paths identified
2017-03-26 08:13:49.768 DEBUG 2426 --- [restartedMain] o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping      : Rejected bean name 'duplicateServerPropertiesDetector': no URL paths identified
2017-03-26 08:13:49.768 DEBUG 2426 --- [restartedMain] o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping      : Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebClientAutoConfiguration$RestTemplateConfiguration': no URL paths identified
2017-03-26 08:13:49.768 DEBUG 2426 --- [restartedMain] o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping      : Rejected bean name 'restTemplateBuilder': no URL paths identified
2017-03-26 08:13:49.768 DEBUG 2426 --- [restartedMain] o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping      : Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebClientAutoConfiguration': no URL paths identified
2017-03-26 08:13:49.768 DEBUG 2426 --- [restartedMain] o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping      : Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration$RestartConfiguration': no URL paths identified
2017-03-26 08:13:49.768 DEBUG 2426 --- [restartedMain] o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping      : Rejected bean name 'classPathFileSystemWatcher': no URL paths identified
2017-03-26 08:13:49.768 DEBUG 2426 --- [restartedMain] o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping      : Rejected bean name 'classPathRestartStrategy': no URL paths identified
2017-03-26 08:13:49.768 DEBUG 2426 --- [restartedMain] o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping      : Rejected bean name 'hateoasObjenesisCacheDisabler': no URL paths identified
2017-03-26 08:13:49.768 DEBUG 2426 --- [restartedMain] o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping      : Rejected bean name 'fileSystemWatcherFactory': no URL paths identified
2017-03-26 08:13:49.768 DEBUG 2426 --- [restartedMain] o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping      : Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.LocalDevToolsAutoConfiguration$LiveReloadConfiguration': no URL paths identified
2017-03-26 08:13:49.768 DEBUG 2426 --- [restartedMain] o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping      : Rejected bean name 'liveReloadServer': no URL paths identified
2017-03-26 08:13:49.768 DEBUG 2426 --- [restartedMain] o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping      : Rejected bean name 'optionalLiveReloadServer': no URL paths identified
2017-03-26 08:13:49.768 DEBUG 2426 --- [restartedMain] o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping      : Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.
...
```

Comment: Did the `book.log` file get created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
logging.level.*=DEBUG
```

When you are specifying package name with logging level it will work for that package only. Either you can define root logger or use * for all packages.

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced this issue, adding logging.level.*=DEBUG didn't helped.

You can try this:

1. **logging.level.root = DEBUG**
2. **logging.level.package_name=DEBUG** 
   Example: logging.level.com.example.controller=DEBUG